# Heartache, too, inspires its own sad curiosity

Tags: meaning

I would like to know the definition of the following "curiosity."

> The times cannot be numbered when Thomas Atkinson will ask, Why? Why? And again Why? (For heartache, too, inspires its own sad curiosity.)

I interpreted "heartache, too, inspires its own sad curiosity." as "heartache, too, brings out the sad curious aspect that the heartache itself has."

Am I interpreting this correctly? If not, how is this "curiosity" defined in dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curiosity is "What is the reason for this heartache?". If the heartache was not there, the curiosity would not have arisen.

Answer (score 0):

People who are curious often ask "why". Therefore, I assume that it is Atkinson who is curious. The sentence in parentheses suggests that some heartache (presumably Atkinson's own heartache) has inspired it.